# Why does ~x on an int result in -(x+1)

Tags: c++, tilde

Why does this code:

```
#include <iostream>
int main ()
{
  int x = 1;
  int y = ~x;
  std::cout << y;
}
```

Always print -(x+1)? If x = 00000001, shoudn't y = 11111110?

Comment: "If x = 00000001, shoudn't y = 11111110?" yes. But `11111110` as signed integer is -2. [Two's Complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)

Comment: `int` has a sign. You might want to try the same with `unsigned int`

Comment: @black-goat: But `y` **is** `1...11111110` in your experiment. What made you think it wasn't in the first place? `-(x+1)` is `-2`, which is `1...11111110` on a 2's-complement system. I.e. everything works exactly as you expected it to.

Comment: If `int` has 32 bits, `~x` is `11111111 11111111 11111111 11111110` in binary. `int` definitely has more than the 8 bits that would result in `11111110`. The logic is the same regardless of the number of bits though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you're on a [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) system. C++ doesn't guaratee that, but all (citation needed?) modern architectures have this property.

Comment: Looks like it is still used today at least specially: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1962756/4342498

Comment: @krzaq Sure its a FAQ, and we're trying to keep it up like that :)