# Subtracting a value from a typedef in C?

Tags: c, winapi

I am reading some Windows API header files and I saw some code that I don't understand:

```
typedef void *HANDLE;

typedef HANDLE DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT;

#define DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT_UNAWARE ((DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT)-1)
```

What does it mean to subtract a value from a `void *` typedef?

Comment: I think it's a cast of (void*) -1, rather than minusing 1 from void*

Comment: Let's say the`#define` wasn't there, then in the code `DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT` will be a pointer to some address. Now let's introduce the `#define`. In all the occurrence of `DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT` there will be a trailing `-1`. That in pointer arithmetic means the address right before.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no subtraction going on - `DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT_UNAWARE` expands to the *value* of `-1` cast as a `void *`.  It appears that it's being used as a sentinel value for the `DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT` type (which is a typedef for `HANDLE`, which is a typedef for `void *`).

Answer (score 5):

It is a cast, not a subtraction.

```
typedef void *HANDLE;
```

Results in a symbol `HANDLE` that is equivalent to `void *`

Then in turn

```
typedef HANDLE DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT;
```

results in a new symbol `DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT` that is equivalent to `void *`

leading to the expression:

```
#define DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT_UNAWARE ((DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT)-1)
```

which is equivalent to:

```
#define DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT_UNAWARE ((void *)-1)
```

meaning that any instance of `DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT_UNAWARE` in source code  expands to `(void *)` at compile-time.

As an aside - Here are the hows and whys:

```
(void *) -1 == (size_t) -1
```

which is `0xFFFFFFFF` on 32 bit machines,
or `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF` on 64 bit machines.

On [twos complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations) implementations of each respective architecture, these values are equivalent to `-1`, making them useful as sentinel values in routines such as [sbrk())](https://linux.die.net/man/2/sbrk) (memory allocation support), or specifying [dots per inch (dpi) awareness context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setprocessdpiawarenesscontext).

*Note*: The above statement is incorrect for ones complement systems, but as indicated by the [answers in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161797/is-ones-complement-a-real-world-issue-or-just-a-historical-one) ones complement is rare, and not likely to be used in any recent large scale commercial environment.

Comment: Both addresses are valid, given the respective architectures. Neither address is the equivalent of `-1`, unless you assume 2s complement representation. Neither architecture mandates it, though Windows' ABI requires it. Lots of wrongs interleaved with rights still yields wrong. Sorry.

Comment: @IInspectable - LOL, no need to be sorry :) It would have been  more correct for me to say _unlikely addresses_ rather than _invalid addresses_, but because _unlikely addresses_ did not add any value, I edited the point away.  As for my assumption of twos complement, again, if debating the point, I think you would win as the world does still contain ones complement environments, albeit rare.  I have also made an edit to address that point.  Thanks for commenting, both points were valid, and needed to be corrected.