# Why are %s and %c considered as the same type by `scanf()` function?

Tags: c, string, char, scanf

```
char c;
printf("%d", scanf("%s", &c)); // prints 1  
printf("%d", scanf("%c", &c)); // prints 1
```

I do not understand why both these statements prints the same value `1`?

As far as I know, `scanf()` returns the number of input items successfully matched and assigned or even zero in the event of an early matching failure. Then is this not the case of mismatching?

What did I miss here?

Comment: @SedatKapanoglu, not quite, I think. It's more about the behavior of `scanf` when the specifier is incorrect.

Comment: @SedatKapanoglu I have already read it before posting here but couldn't get my answer

Comment: This is definitely not a dup of the proposed question. In the proposed question the difference between the two items is truly being asked about. In this question, the poster is very incorrectly assuming that the format has bearing in the return value of `scanf()`.

Comment: Duplicate is about use of `"%s"` and `"%c"` in `printf()`, not `scanf()` as used here.  Vote to re-open as that [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10846024/why-does-cs-printf-format-string-have-both-c-and-s), though related, does not apply.

Comment: \o/ UB all round \o/

Comment: @PrinceVijayPratap gotcha. cool.

Comment: This is invalid code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both the format specifiers `%c` and `%s` expect an argument of type `char*` when used in `scanf` family of functions.

The difference is that use of `%c` will read at most one character to it while use of `%s` will read all non-whitespace characters it finds. It will also add a terminating null character to the pointer when `%s` is used.

Given

```
char c;
```

Using

```
scanf("%s", &c);
```

is a problem since `&c` has only one valid character that can be written to. Hence, it leads to use of memory that the program is not supposed to, which in turn leads to undefined behavior.

The fact that

```
printf("%d", scanf("%s", &c))
```

prints `1` instead of crashing is a matter of *bad luck*. It would have been nice had the program crashed. Then you would know that the program is wrong.

Comment: Good/important detail about what `"%s"` does.

Answer (score 5):

> `%s and %c are used for different types`

is incorrect.  They both expect the same type: `char *`.

---

`"%c"` expects a `char *` that points to 1 `char`.

`"%s"` expects a `char *` that points to an array big enough for the string.  This needs to be at least 2 `char`.  OP code likely writes past `c`.  It is undefined behavior to write past the variable's space.

---

Instead

```
char s[10];
printf("%d", scanf("%9s", s));
char c;
printf("%d", scanf("%c", &c));
```

Comment: then why there ever be a type `char` in c

Comment: @Prince Vijay Pratap Why `char` exist? That is a broad question.  So we can code with 1 `char` at a time.   The use for `scanf(%c, &ch)` to to read **1** `char`.  `scanf(%9s, s)` reads up to 9 `char` and forms a string.

Answer (score 3):

With a definition like

```
char c;
```

using

```
scanf("%s", &ch);  // "" s added
```

causes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).<sup>*</sup> Then, the output cannot be justified in any way.

---

Note: `%s` format specifier expects the corresponding argument to be a pointer to a char array of sufficient length. Otherwise, there will be memory boundary overrun, which will cause UB.

To quote `C11` standard, chapter §7.21.6.2, related to `%s` format specifier,

> [...] the corresponding argument shall be a
>   pointer to the initial element of a character array large enough to accept the
>   sequence and a terminating null character, which will be added automatically.