# How to print this string in C

Tags: c, string, printf

I'm having trouble printing out this string in C

```
char *myXMLString = 
"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>"
"<painting>"
"   <img src=\"madonna.jpg\" alt=\"Foligno Madonna, by Raphael\"/>"
"   <caption>MY_REPLACED_TEXT"
"   <date>1511</date>-<date>1512</date>.</caption>"
"</painting>";
```

If I use printf("%c",*myXMLString); I get expected parameter declarator missing. Tried sprintf with similar results.

Comment: `myXMLString` is a C-style string, not a single character. Therefore, you cannot use `%c` for that (unless you only need to print the first character of that string). In this case, you could do `printf(myXMLString);` or if you need to add other data, for example a newline you could use `printf("%s\n", myXMLString);`. You can find more background here: [Why does C's printf format string have both %c and %s?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10846024/why-does-cs-printf-format-string-have-both-c-and-s)

Comment: By the way, myXMLString should be declared a `const char*`, since it points to a string constant rather than a writable character array. Otherwise you should use `char myXMLString[] = ...`

Answer (score 2):

```
printf("%s", myXMLString);
```

is how you print a C-string. `%s` is the format to be used for priting strings. See the [man page of printf](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) for details.

On the other hand, if you could't figure this out yourself, you really need to study a proper textbook or at least a tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

```
  fprintf(adgfile, "%s", myXMLString);
```