# Select every second element from array using lambda

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

C# 4.0. How can the following be done using lambda expressions?

```
int[] a = new int[8] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
// Now fetch every second element so that we get { 0, 2, 4, 6 }
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
int[] list = a.Where((value, index) => index % 2 == 0)
              .ToArray();
```

It will only select even indexes, as calculate by the `%` (mod) operator .

```
5 % 2 // returns 1
4 % 2 // returns 0
```

According to MSDN:

> [% Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4e0fzs%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: +1, I forgot, that `where` also has overload with index :)

Answer (score 10):

Another approach using `Enumerable.Range`

```
var result = Enumerable.Range(0, a.Length/2)
                       .Select(i => a[2*i])
                       .ToArray();
```

Or use *bitwise* for more efficient to check *even*:

```
var result = a.Where((i, index) => (index & 1) == 0)
              .ToArray();
```

Comment: +1 for bitwise odd/even test which is by far more efficient than '%' operator. So classy :-)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229107/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-find-if-a-number-is-even-or-odd

Answer (score 8):

The remainder operator is your friend.

```
int[] everySecond = a.Where((i, ind) => ind % 2 == 0).ToArray();
```

[% Operator (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4e0fzs.aspx)

> The % operator computes the remainder after dividing its first operand
>   by its second. All numeric types have predefined remainder operators.

[E.Lippert: What's the difference? Remainder vs Modulus](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/12/05/what-s-the-difference-remainder-vs-modulus.aspx)