# whats wrong with this odd number program?

Tags: c++, c

I want to find out if a number is odd or not.
I want to compare the LSB and not use modulo.

```
int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{
    if ( argc >1 ) {
        if ( atoi(argv[1]) & 0x1 == 1 ) 
            printf ("odd num \n");
    }
    return 0;
}


# ./odd 2
# ./odd 3
odd num 
# ./odd 22
# ./odd 23
# ./odd 33
odd num 
# ./odd 43
# ./odd 52
odd num 
# file odd
odd: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=0x56f7eb1e7a35762bd8b786eefb5516a14549fc1f, not stripped
```

Comment: That's not how you convert a string into an integer.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [What is the fastest way to find if a number is even or odd?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229107/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-find-if-a-number-is-even-or-odd)

Comment: @StephenCanon The brain should be the first choice. If that is insufficient, switch to the debugger.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are confusing numbers with representations of numbers. The input to this program is a representation of a number like "22" (the decimal digit "2" repeated twice), not a number like twenty two (the one that comes after twenty one). Telling the compiler to pretend it's a number won't work.

```
   if ( *(unsigned int*)argv[1] & 0x1 == 1 )
```

Since `argv[1]` is a pointer to a string, telling the compiler to pretend it's a pointer to an unsigned integer will give you garbage.

Your probably want `atoi(argv[1])`, which converts a string that represents a number in decimal form into the number it represents.

Comment: Isn't he checking the first argument's first character's least significant bit?

Comment: Crud, I had it right the first time. Editing ...

Comment: Yes, and "garbage" better describes what happens. It's only the first char when on a little-endian machine and if you're unlucky enough to have an aligned pointer (or have a machine that doesn't give you bus errors...).

Comment: I'm fairly sure you know of many better ways than `atoi`.