# How does this code check for parity of a number? (even or odd)

Tags: rust, bitwise-operators, bitwise-and, parity

I came across this piece of code on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/zgxc5b/comment/izk1ggj/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)

```rust
1 - ((num & 1) << 1) as i32
```

This code returns 1 for even numbers and -1 for odd numbers.

It takes less instructions than [other](https://rust.godbolt.org/z/Wej4aEo3v) ways of calculating the same thing, and is presumably, quite fast. So, **how does it work**? (A step-by-step breakdown would be helpful)

Note: I found [What is the fastest way to find if a number is even or odd?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229107/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-find-if-a-number-is-even-or-odd), but don't understand how that works either.

Comment: Have you read about bitwise operators? Try writing down the effects of each operation, outside to inside, using e.g. 0b00000001 for `num`.

Comment: @hnefatl, I actually dont understand how 1-() works on u32.

Comment: It doesn't check the parity of `num`; it computes `pow(-1, num)`. The parity check is just `num & 1`; the rest turns that into `-1` or `1` as appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's break this down from the inside out.

1. `num & 1`

This "masks" all but the least significant bit using a bitwise and. Since the least significant bit is the "ones" place, it will evaluate to `1` if the number is odd or `0` if the number is even.

2. `(result1) << 1`

This bitshifts that left by 1. This has the effect of multiplying by two. If `num` was odd, this will evaluate to `2` or still `0` if `num` was even. (0 * 2 = 0)

3. `(result2) as i32`

This casts the resulting unsigned integer (`2` or `0`) into a signed integer, allowing us to subtract it in the next operation. This is only for the compiler, it has no effect on the value in memory.

4. `1 - result3`

This subtracts the previous number from `1`. If `num` was even, we get `1 - 0` which results in a final answer of `1`. If `num` was odd, we get `1 - 2` which results in a final answer of `-1`.

Comment: Wait, the `as i32` is evaluated before? Ok, that makes sense now. Thank you.