# Inline function and & Operator in C++

Tags: c++

What does this function do ?

```
inline bool myFunc(int aVal) {return aVal & 1;}
```

Edit
I have edited the code to be runnable.

Comment: tells you if its an odd number

Comment: @cmd They want a description.

Comment: It doesn't compile because the compiler doesn't know what `Inline` is

Comment: A long description can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/160930/how-do-i-check-if-an-integer-is-even-or-odd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keyword `inline` shall be written with lower case letters.

```
inline bool myFunc(int aVal) {return aVal & 1;}
```

The function returns `true` if the first bit of the value aVal is set to 1. Otherwise it returns `false`.

Using this function you can check for example whether aVal is odd or even number. :) If the function will return `true` then it means that the number is odd.

The operator & is bitwise AND operator.

Comment: Thank You for the description :)