# Infinite loop when simplifying fractions in binary in C

Tags: c, linux, binary, infinite-loop, fractions

I'm trying to simplify fractions in binary with this code that checks if the value is even:

```
int is_even(floatlet value){
  if(value & 1) return 0;
  return 1;
}
```

And this while loop keeps bit shifting until the value is odd.

```
while(is_even(numerator) && is_even(denomExp)){
  numerator >>= 1;
  denomExp <<= 1;
}
```

The while loop goes on an infinite loop. I'm wondering why?
We've done test and the is_even function works fine. Thanks!

Comment: What is a `floatlet`?  What are the types of `numerator` and `denominator`?

Comment: a) 0 is even and so is 0/2 and 0 * 2. b) You haven't bothered to show the declarations or values of numerator and denomExp ... how can you possibly expect anyone to answer your question without those?

Comment: It's a minature floating point representation of a floating point number in 8 bits. Numerator and denominator are just integers.

Comment: P.S. If you care about speed: #define is_even(x) !((x) & 1)

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by *minature floating point representation of a floating point number in 8 bits*... your test for evenness may be incorrect.

Comment: @chqrlie It's presumably a mantissa and exponent crammed into 8 bits. Presumably the exponent is in the high bits ... otherwise is_even is indeed wrong.

Comment: Please post the complete type definition and the complete code.  Your question is incomplete without those.

Comment: @JimBalter Firstly, there is no evidence that the compiler doesn't inline that function, meaning there is no evidence that your code would speed anything up. Secondly...

Comment: @skaggs `value & 1` isn't necessary a test for evenness. If you care about portability, use `value % 2`. [It'll probably be just as fast.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/160935/1989425)

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour You're right ... that was silly of me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop is incorrect: you should be shifting `demonExp` to the right too.
It runs indefinitely for `numerator=0` and an even `denomExp`.

If `numerator` and `denomExp` are integer types, and the number is just a fraction `numerator/denomExp`, you can fix the code this way:

```
while (numerator && is_even(numerator) && is_even(denomExp)) {
    numerator >>= 1;
    denomExp >>= 1;
}
```

Conversely, if `denomExp` is the power of 2 by which to divide the numerator, you should increment it instead, and maybe test for overflow:

```
while (numerator && is_even(numerator)) {
    numerator >>= 1;
    denomExp += 1;
}
```

You must post the type definition and semantics as well as the complete code in question.

Comment: If denomExp is an exponent, then they should be decrementing it, not shifting it.

Comment: @Cameron Skaggs: Agreed!  post the complete type definition and the complete code!

Comment: "you should increment it" -- oh yeah, that's what I meant. :-) (And I'm not Cameron Skaggs.)

Comment: thanks for the help, after taking the exponent and increment it instead of shifting it the loop stopped. I appreciate the help!