# how can we figureout a number is even or odd, with out using division(/) or percentile (%) symbols

Tags: java

how can we figure-out a number is even or odd, with out using division(/) or percentile (%) symbols.

This one of the interview asked to me. Asked me to write program using java.

We should not use arithmetic symbols like division(/) , percentile (%).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without using division or modulo, the only thing that comes to mind is checking if the last digit is in the set [ 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 ], like so:

```
public static boolean isEven(int testNumber) {

  String strI = Integer.toString(testNumber);
  String lastCharacter = strI.substring(strI.length() - 1);
  return ("13579".indexOf(lastCharacter) == -1);

}
```

That would produce:

```
System.out.println ( isEven( 10) );  // true
System.out.println ( isEven( 11) );  // false
System.out.println ( isEven( 999) ); // false
```

Good enough?

Comment: Excellent answer, it works for me. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Although I'm reasonably sure that to generate a string representation toString *does* use division and modulo. Shouldn't @AmirPashazadeh's be the accepted answer, since pure bit shifting should not involve division?

Comment: I think you're right but not for that reason. OP said don't "use arithmetic symbols like division(/) , percentile (%)" -- so toString is legit within those parameters (not using "the symbols"). But -- that "like" means that the exercise was probably to avoid *all* arithmetical symbols, so I failed with my "-".

Answer (score 4):

Shift right and then shift left the number, if it remains the same number is even, otherwise it is odd.

Answer (score 2):

```
boolean isOdd = (yourInteger&1)==1;
```

That is from the link provided by Christopher  [How do I check if an integer is even or odd?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160930/how-do-i-check-if-an-integer-is-even-or-odd)

Comment: That link also indicates that this technique doesn't work universally for negative numbers (in c, anyway). Thoughts?

Comment: Java always uses twos complement, so it should always work. Even with the other integer data types.