# How to prompt user for a number until they choose an Odd number? C++

Tags: c++, loops

```
int main() {
    int num;
    cout << "Enter a number: ";
    cin >> num;
    cout << "you entered ";
    cout << num;
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

---

How will a program know when an odd number is input by the user?

For an "If statement"... I can't say If (num == odd) { cout << "all done"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check if an integer is even or odd?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/160930/how-do-i-check-if-an-integer-is-even-or-odd)

Comment: You'll need to look at loops. Do-while loop is probably what you're looking for. Do "prompt" while "num % 2 != 0"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the [Modulus Operator](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/modulus.html), you can detect whether a number is even or odd. You can think of the modulus operator (%) as giving you the 'remainder' after a division. For example, 12 % 2 would give you 0. 13 % 2 would give you 1. In this way, just do

```
if (variable % 2 == 1)
```

to check if your variable is odd.

Comment: Played around with this idea for about an hour and ended up getting it. Thank you..

Comment: You're welcome!
Do you mind upvoting or accepting my answer? Trying to raise my score :)

Comment: Yes sir! won't let me up vote because I am too new to the site but I accepted answer. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

we can use the **modulo** operator to know if the user is giving us an odd number.
For example, let us write a code where we have to keep taking input from user until the user enters an odd number.

```
# include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int n;
    do
    {
        printf("Enter a number: ");
        scanf("%d",&n);
        printf("The number you entered: %d\n",n);
    } while (n%2==0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Minor nit-pick: Formally, `%` in C++ is the **remainder** operator (not modulo). The difference is very subtle but can be significant when negative numbers are involved.

Comment: Surprising that, after 7 years, nobody has come up with `n & 1` to isolate the lowest bit.