# Sorting numbers in C

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

I have created a small C program which sorts odd and even numbers in descending order, with the user inputting whether they wish to sort the odd or the even numbers. So in order to try and make it more complex, I was wondering if there was a way in which I could have my program sort only the even numbers while leaving the odd numbers in their current place and vice versa so for instance:

Input:

odd

1 7 3 5 2 4 20

Output:

1 3 5 7 2 4 20

There is probably multiple ways to go about this, I'm wanting to include it in

Comment: There should be a way, but it's a very broad question for this site.

Comment: I couldn't find anything on the web in relation to sorting only specific numbers and leaving the rest unaltered, so any information is good.

Comment: Try extracting only the even numbers to a new array, sort that, and then loop to insert into the old array only when the value in the old array at the given index is even.

Comment: Thanks AntonH, I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should place the sort algorithm in a separate function. Secondly you can add one more parameter that will specify the predicate for elements of the array that need to be sorted.

For example

```
#include <stdio.h>

void sort( int a[], size_t n, int predicate( int ) )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        if ( predicate( a[i] ) )
        {
            for ( size_t j = i + 1; j < n; j++ )
            {
                if ( predicate( a[j] ) && a[i] < a[j] )
                {
                    int tmp = a[i];
                    a[i] = a[j];
                    a[j] = tmp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}   

int even( int x ) { return ( x & 1 ) == 0; }
int odd( int x ) { return ( x & 1 ); }

int main(void) 
{
    int a[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    const size_t N = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ ) printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    putchar( '\n' );

    sort( a, N, even );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ ) printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    putchar( '\n' );

    sort( a, N, odd );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ ) printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
8 1 6 3 4 5 2 7 0 9 
8 9 6 7 4 5 2 3 0 1
```

Comment: A very portable "even" test is `( x %2 ) == 0` as `( x & 1 ) == 0` fails with  rare 1's complement platforms.  A 2's complement platform with an optimizing compiler will emit efficient code just like `x&1 == 0` for original code `( x %2 ) == 0`. [ref](http://stackoverflow.com/q/160930/2410359)

Comment: @chux This does not make sense because positive and negative zeroes compared with zero yield true.

Comment: The comment is unclear to me.  How would `(x%2) == 0` not work for you?

Comment: @chux I did not say that it won't work.

Comment: What specifically is your concern then with [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42708001/sorting-numbers-in-c/42708303?noredirect=1#comment72558646_42708303)?

Comment: @chux I pointed out that you can compare negative and positive zeroes with zero and the result will be true independing on the sign of the zero.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137773/discussion-between-chux-and-vlad-from-moscow).

Comment: @chux I am sorry I do not take part in chats.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like, if the number is divisible by 2(remainder 0) it is even, so do nothing. If the number + 1 is divisible by 2(and so is odd), then sort.

Answer (score 0):

> ... sort only the even numbers while leaving the odd numbers in their current place and vice versa

When encountering a value that matches `SkipType`, skip that array element.

```
// Return true when odd, else false
bool IsOdd(int x) {
  return x%2;  // x%2 --> -1,0,1
}

...
// Select skipping odd or even
bool SkipType = IsOdd(1);

for (i = 0; i < ArraySize; ++i) {
  if (IsOdd(number[i]) == SkipType) continue;
  for (j = i + 1; j < ArraySize /*size*/; ++j) {
    if (IsOdd(number[j]) == SkipType) continue;
    if (number[i] > number[j]) {  // I think OP want > here, not <
      a = number[i];
      number[i] = number[j];
      number[j] = a;
    }
  }
}
```