# How to check an number is odd or even in loadrunner

Tags: loadrunner

I want to check a run time parameter is odd or even  in loadrunner.

I tried the below step, but not working as expected:

```
if (atoi(lr_eval_string("{xxxxx}") ) & 1)
```

Comment: C Programming exercise, The remainder is zero even numbers - http://www.codingalpha.com/find-remainder-c-program/

Comment: Also you can try modulo operator.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check if an integer is even or odd?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160930/how-do-i-check-if-an-integer-is-even-or-odd)

Answer (score 0):

It requires basic C programming skills. Below is the code which helps you in loadrunner.

```
if ((atoi(lr_eval_string("{xxxxx}")) % 2) == 0) 
{
lr_output_message("Even Number");
}
elseif ((atoi(lr_eval_string("{xxxxx}")) % 2) != 0)
{
lr_output_message("Odd Number");
}
else
{
lr_output_message("Number is zero");
}
```