# How to identify if a number is odd or even by it's last digit in C++?

Tags: c++, if-statement

hello Im still new at programming so sorry if it's a dumb question but what's the error in my program? every number I input it will always say it's an odd number and the else statement doesn't work.

```
cout << "This program will determine whether a number is odd or even. \n";
cout << "Please enter a number ---> ";
cin >> number;

lastDigit = number % 10;

if ( number % 10 == 1,3,5,7,9)
{
    cout << "\nThe last digit is " << lastDigit;
    cout << endl << number << " is odd.";
}

else
{
    cout << "\nThe last digit is " << lastDigit;
    cout << endl << number << " is even.";
}

getch ();   
return 0;
```

}`

Comment: Convert to a string. Get last character. Is it an even number?

Comment: Tip: `if ( number % 10 == 1,3,5,7,9)` is not doing what you think it does.

Comment: You normally check whether a number is odd by computing the remainder of division by 2 since "being odd" means "not being divisible by 2"

Comment: `cin`ing it as a string directly and checking the last character would seem to be the simplest solution in your case, though `% 2` is generally how you tell if something is even or odd.

Comment: Related:duplicate: [How do I check if an integer is even or odd?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160930/)

Answer (score 2):

`if ( number % 10 == 1,3,5,7,9)` is the problem here. Although it compiles, that's not doing what you intend.

The `,` syntax here does not mean "one of", it means, effectively, ["but then"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) which is not what you want. This ends up evaluating as `if (9)` as the other parts are evaluated and the results discarded.

This can be done with a `switch`:

```c
switch (number % 10) {
  case 1:
  case 3:
  ...
  case 9:
    // Odd!!
    break;
  default:
    // Even!
}
```

What you really need is just `if (number % 2)` as that's how "evenness" is decided. If that's true, you have an odd number, otherwise even.

Answer (score 1):

`if ( number % 10 == 1,3,5,7,9)` is not doing what you think it actually  does.
What is actually required to check  whether a number is odd or even is :

//n  -----> number

//l------->lastdigit of the number

```
    l = n % 10; 

    if(l % 2 == 0)
    {printf("%d is even:", l);}
    
    else
    {printf("%d is odd:", l); }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lastDigit = number % 10;

if ( lastDigit % 2 == 1)
{
    cout << "\nThe last digit is " << lastDigit;
    cout << endl << number << " is odd.";
}
else
{
    cout << "\nThe last digit is " << lastDigit;
    cout << endl << number << " is even.";
}
```